# I attract nails, but I'm not magnetic

Tags: riddle

> Countless things are the cause of me.
>
> I attract nails, but I'm not magnetic.
>
> What can I be?

Comment: do the nails refer to rot13(svatreanvyf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> An itchy rash

Countless things are the cause of me.

> Poison ivy, sicknesses(chicken pox), bug bites, and food allergys can all cause an itchy rash.

I attract nails, but I'm not magnetic.

> You may try to scratch an itch with you finger nails.

Comment: Hi @riskymysteries, if you're posting a comment with information that contains information about the answer, you can put it in rot13 like this: rot13(Jrypbzr gb Chmmyvat.fr!), then it doesn't give spoilers to future users. I use rot13.com for my translations.